# How can I install TextWrap plugin in Gedit?

Tags: 12.04, gedit, plugins

I followed a guide to install Text Wrap in Gedit. Tried to get standard error feedback by starting from a terminal. But couldn't get it installed.

Would there be a problem with 12.04 having gone Python 2.7? Other suggestions?
I had the same problem earlier in 11.10.

Answer (score 1):

Just installed **Text Wrap** in Gedit and it's working fine for me! Follow these steps to install:

- Download [Text Wrap](https://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins) and put both files (`toggletextwrap.plugin` and `toggletextwrap.py`) in your home directory.
- Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open terminal and run following command:

  ```
  sudo mv ~/toggletextwrap.plugin toggletextwrap.py /usr/lib/gedit/plugins
  ```
- Now open Gedit and navigate to `Edit > Preferences > Plugins`
- Scroll down and enable Text Wrap. That's it!

Comment: I was trying to install TextWrap as opposed to ToggleTextWrap and your procedure did not work. Following your link brought home the difference: my TextWrap was still for Gedit 2, not 3. Look at the value of the parameter IAge in the plugin file: it should be 3! So your answer did help, thanks.